# Insert Grid View column value into Textbox and dropdown on button control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, findcontrol

[image: As i mention in image my output should be on Proceed button event]

I want to Fill gridview column value into given control 
something like Project Title value fill inside project Title text box Problem ID fill inside Selected Problem Dropdown and so on... on button click even

i have taken as control name

Project title as txtProjectTitle,

selectProblem Id as ddlSelectProblem,

Project_Start_Date as txtProjectStartDate,

Project_Target_Date as TextBox1,

gridview as GrdTemp,

Procedd button as Button2_Click
ASPX CODE:

```
     [![<asp:GridView ID="GrdTemp" runat="server" Style="width: 100%; text-align: center" class="table table-striped table-bordered" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
         <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No." HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
         <ItemTemplate>
         <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>' ID="lblID"></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Title">
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Project_Title") %>' ID="lblID"></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Problem ID">
         <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Problem") %>' ID="lblID"></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Start Date">
        <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Project_Start_Date") %>' ID="lblID</asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Target Date">
       <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Project_Target_Date") %>' ID="lblID"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>                                                            </asp:GridView>][2]][2]
```

C# code:

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = (sender as Label).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            TextBox txtProject = row.FindControl("txtProjectTitle") as TextBox;
            txtProject.Text = Convert.ToString((row.Parent.Parent as GridView).DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["Project_Title"]);
            DropDownList ddlProblem = row.FindControl("ddlSelectProblem") as DropDownList;
            ddlSelectProblem.SelectedItem.Text = Convert.ToString((row.Parent.Parent as GridView).DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["Problem"]);
            txtProjectStartDate.Text = Convert.ToString((row.Parent.Parent as GridView).DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["Project_Start_Date"]);
            TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString((row.Parent.Parent as GridView).DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["Project_Target_Date"]);
        }
```

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: its showing Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I got My output as i need Thanx for response